# Why there is a 't' in front of column while using stream resolution return byte array outputstream?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using Spring framework, and use streamresolution to return a .txt file for user to download.

The result of data is fine, however, there is a 't' in front of every column of data,
and besides the last column, there is a 'w' in the end of every column.

I can't not understand why because the data seems fine, and I didn't told the program to create the letter.

Here is my code:

```
// A list of String, which are the data, it might looks like 20200810,a,b,c,100,55,.....
// the whole is a String contains comma
List<String> dataList = (List<String>) parameters.get("myData");

ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
StreamingResolution streamingResolution = null;

ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);

oos.writeObject("\n");
for (String s : dataList) {
    oos.writeObject(s.trim());
    oos.writeUTF("\n");
}

streamingResolution = new StreamingResolution("text/plain", new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray()));

streamingResolution.setCharacterEncoding(CharEncoding.UTF_8);
            
String year = Integer.toString((Integer.parseInt(end.substring(0, 4));
String day = year + end.substring(4, 6);

oos.close();

return streamingResolution.setFilename(day + ".txt");
```

while I download the data, 202108.txt
it might looks like

t ?0210810,a,b,c,100,55w

t ?0210810,d,e,f,99,60

could anyone please tell me why there would be a 't' in the front
and a 'w' in the end?
And how to fix this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're trying to read binary data as text. I'm surprised it's as sensible as it is.

Comment: May I would like it to be smarter just for this time, knowing what I want it to be. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses an [`ObjectOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html), which is used to write serialized Java data in a binary format. It is not a plain text format, and should not be used in this way. The extra characters are bytes that are defined in the [Java Object Serialization Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/serialization/protocol.html).

To write plain text, you can use the `java.io.PrintStream` class instead. For example:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream, false, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

printStream.println();
for (String s : dataList) {
    printStream.println(s.trim());
}
printStream.flush();

StreamingResolution streamingResolution = new StreamingResolution("text/plain", new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray()));

streamingResolution.setCharacterEncoding(CharEncoding.UTF_8);
```

Note that I also simplified the code by moving the `streamingResolution` local variable declaration to where it is assigned.

This is a straightforward translation of the code provided, to show you how to use the  `PrintStream` class, however it may not be the best way to write it. The `StreamingResolution` class appears to be part of the [Stripes Framework](https://github.com/StripesFramework/stripes/blob/master/stripes/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/stripes/action/StreamingResolution.java). It is intended for streaming large responses to the client. However, this implementation does not actually stream the response, it accumulates it into a byte array. A better way to implement this would be to subclass the `StreamingResponse` class, as described in the Stripe documentation, to write directly to the response:

```
return new StreamingResolution("text/plain") {
    public void stream(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println();
        for (String s : dataList) {
            out.println(s.trim());
        }
        out.flush();
    }
}.setFilename(day + ".txt");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your great answer. It did solved my problem, thanks. I have changed my code, and use PrintStream, the program worked fine, and the result is exactly what I want. Thanks. Only thing I change is that while I use new PrintStream, it said that the parameter should be (outputstream, boolean, string), so I wrote 
`PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream, false, UTF-8);`
The below code seems even more better, since I alread got one work code, I would like to try another. Thank you for your answer again.

Comment: My pleasure. I'm glad it  helped! I should have mentioned, the `PrintStream` constructor I used was introduced in Java 10. Using the version that takes a `String` is totally fine, too, and  more backwards compatible.

Comment: Oh, I see. I have tried both of the code, and they work very well. The streamingResponse seems to be faster than another. Thank you for the answer and the great example code. ^^